# mod_rewrite: set custom header through .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'have this rewrite condition that redirect all the request of non-existing files to the app.php in parent directory.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On


RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond $1#%{REQUEST_URI} ([^#]*)#(.*)\1$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %2../app.php [L]
```

In the last line (rewriterule) the value of $1 is the path relative to the dir where .htacces is, in order to make it portable ( found here: http://linlog.skepticats.com/entries/2014/08/Using_RewriteBase_without_knowing_it.php ).

That is : calling http://localhost/myapp/public/test123/r.txt  I will get test123/r.txt in $1 variable (considering that .htaccess is in public/).

I would like to pass the value of $1 to the app.php, a common solution would be to append it as a query string:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %2../app.php?__path=$1 [L]
```

In this way I have __path as a GET variable  (PHP: $_REQUEST["__path"]) , but how it works with other kind of requests like POST (query string should not be there) ?

A more clean solution would be to put $1 in a HTTP custom header but, how can I set a custom header, say MYAPP_PATH to $1 value through .htacess ?

Comment: PS: I've noticed that the trick ?__path=$1 overrides all the querystring that I pass in the original URL. So passing something through a custom header seems to be the only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with your comment:

> I've noticed that the trick ?__path=$1 overrides all the querystring that I pass in the original URL.

[You forgot to set the `QSA` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa).

Second to the core question:

> In this way I have __path as a GET variable (PHP: $_REQUEST["__path"]) , but how it works with other kind of requests like POST (query string should not be there) ?

This just works fine. GET-parameters are just popularly called that, they're actually *query string parameters* and can be passed with any HTTP verb, from GET and POST to PUT and DELETE. So if you POST to a URL with query string parameters you can still read them from `$_GET` just fine.

Final point, as the above solves all your issues: please do not use `$_REQUEST`. It's really *REALLY* bad practice, and may lead to obscure security and stability issues. Just use `$_POST`, `$_GET` et al instead.

Comment: Ok, the problem is that if someone could override using http:/localhost/myapp/public/path?__path=newpath ... with this $_GET["__path"] is equals to newpath instead of path. Well, it's not a real problem considering that the request can be forged.